# Edit a value and post to http with HttpPost

Tags: java, http-post, form-submit, apache-httpclient-4.x

The problem:I have a few forms in the html page which I want to edit, then submit the data.

I have read about entities in HttpClient, and I came across the UrlEncodedFormEntity, which as far as I understand you add parameters to it and then you can post them. I find this ok, but I thought is there a different way to post the changed attributes, since jsoup has a convenient method to set a value in an attribute. this is what I tried using a different entity, StringEntity:

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    post.setHeader("Accept",
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    post.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
    post.setHeader("Cookie", getCookies());
    post.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(updatedHTML, ContentType.TEXT_HTML));

    HttpResponse response = null;
    response = client.execute(post);
```

where `updatedHTML` is the full html code with the changes I want to post.
but as you guessed, its not working.

edit: I don't think it's the problem, but I also have a sumbit button, which I ignored here, should it also be considered in the `updatedHTML`?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things are wrong in your approach.
you cannot pass an html in the StringEntity as it is not the usage of the class
The StringEntity, as well as its derived classes, is intended to carry messages.
The second error is that you seem to use the library to change the html.
You need to work on what you are posting. Here an example.

```
    List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("your parameter name","your parameter value"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("another parameter name","another paramete value"));
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/");
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I made some assumptions:
you have in your hands all the parameters you are passing (simply you will change the approach not working on the html but on the url)
The exception handling is not considered in my snippet. The code is a simple example to show you how to deal with forms
Note also that the UrlEncodedFormEntity will handle the parameters for you. E.g. in our example>
your parameter name=your parameter value&another parameter name=another parameter value

Comment: I already knew what you wrote, I thought maybe there is a way to post html source code and not params, apparently there isn't.

Comment: Well, I couldn't know it :-). If you want to work changing  somehow the html I would choose a different approach.